# "proper" eliptical orbit's for planets around the sun using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, orbit

For a school assignment I have been told to make a model of the solar system using OpenGL, C++ and a framework developed bye the school. Right now I have the sun, earth and the moon orbiting correctly compared to one another in a flat plane (x axis). Since the distance between the sun and the earth is slightly elliptic i use average distances between all the objects which are scaled down bye a global factor. However i would like to update my model to use proper elliptical orbits.

I have found some data used bye cosmologists however it uses a completely different co-ordinate system compared to what I'm used to (, so without any pre-written tools to convert them and potentially change the center of rotation (most of them use the earth while I would like to use the sun) is something which is a bit beyond my capabilities with respect to physics and mathematics. It's also not a requirement with respect to the assignment. Does anyone know if there is a simpler way of doing this? Or should i just stick to crude flat models of the solar system?

NB: I don't mind if the utility or library I'm using has to convert the orbits as a separate process prior to feeding it to my OpenGL related code.

Comment: I guess the conversion between those coordinate systems has to be figured out. Consider also math.SO and physics.SO for that, there maybe some experts in the area. Also we need more details: what coordinate system, links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the equations for ellipses, you can just base the orbits off the aphelion (furthest distance from the sun) and perihelion (closest distance to the sun) both of which you should be able to find online. The sun should be located at the one of the foci of the ellipse.

If you wanted you simulation to be more accurate, you could take into account Kepler's second law which says that, "A line joining a planet and the Sun sweeps out equal areas during equal intervals of time."